# ObjectDisposedException at form close

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have an app in visual studio 2005 sp1, implemented in motorola mc2100 with windows ce 6.0, the application works fine until you close it then gives an error:

Error:
vb_scansample2.exe (app name)
ObjectDisposedException

at
system.windows.forms.control.invokehelper(delegate method, boolean fsynchronous, object[] rgobjargs)
at
system.windows.forms.control.invokehelper(delegate method, object[] args)
at
symbol.barcode.ActionsEventFiringThread()

any help?

Answer (score 0):

The barcode actions object is raising an event.  That event is trying to update something in the UI, but the UI is already torn down.  Wrap the event handler logic in a `try/catch` and ignore `ObjectDisposedExceptions`, or better yet, unhook the event when you're disposing.

Comment: The application have only one form, the error is show after the application is close, there are any way to know what event persist when the application is closed?

Comment: Unhook any and all events that you have hooked in your app.